# Unique twitter oauth help

Tags: twitter, oauth, authorization

I have done a lot of research on this issue without any success.

The oauth system used by twitter assumes you have a single application that can store the auth key, my situation is different. I have an application sitting behind a firewall that can get the required tokens, however the callback cannot get through to the application due to firewall rules.

I have tried changing the firewall rules but the people in charge of the servers refuse to do so at any cost, they also refuse to allow the website any write access to the one and only shared point of the application - the database.

The public facing area of the website has no way of giving information back to the internal web admin area, it is a one way transaction:

webadmin -> firewall -> (rw) database (ro) -> firewall -> website -> firewall

I need to authorize webadmin to allow it to post to twitter.

I can get the temp auth key and can redirect to twitter, but the twitter callback with the final authorization key can only get to the public facing website (10 physical servers) which have no way of talking to the webadmin so I can never complete the cycle of oauth.

I have tried saving to files and copy/pasting the auth code across but for some reason it blocks any tweets made if the oauth key is copied in this manner.

I have gone grey and am now bald trying to get this simple change in place,

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the user adding the Twitter account can visit webadmin in a browser and webadmin stores some sort of temporary sessions so to know what user is currently visiting it you don't need to mess with firewalls and nothing from from Twitter or outside of your firewall needs to connect into your network.

The basics of how this works is is as follows: 1) User visits webadmin and has a request token generated. The request token is temporarily storred in a session. 2) The user is redirected to twitter.com with the public half of the request token where they authorize access. 3) The user gets redirected to webadmin which they can get to because they are they user within the firewall. 4) The request token can no be exchanged for an access token to be saved permanently and used to interact with the Twitter API as the user.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I found that i could not get the authorization to work on webadmin directly due the to restictions placed on the network, which is why i had to get the workaround working. Anyway i managed to solve the issue by convincing the sysadmins to allow temporary write access to one table in the database and switching it off after the authorisation was completed.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something about your network but If the webadmin can be viewed in a browser there should not be an issue. Glad you got it working regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter supports [xAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) on special request, which doesn't require that kind of callback, and might just work with your firewall. You basically just have to make the case as to why you need to use xAuth instead of OAuth, and then you use a slightly different request structure.